# I use this code for media query in scss not working

Tags: html, css, sass

I use this code for media query in scss not working

```
.navb-header{
    .navbar-brand{
        img{
            width:125px;
            @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
                width: 345px;
            }
        }
    }
    #navbarTogglerDemo02{
        ul{
            li.nav-item{
                padding: 0 10px;
                a{
                    font-weight: 500;
                    color: #000;
                    font-size: 16px;
                    text-transform: uppercase;
                    transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
                    position: relative;
                    &:before{
                        content:'';
                        position: absolute;
                        width: 100%;
                        height: 2px;
                        border:1px solid #333;
                        bottom:0;
                        left: 0;
                        opacity: 0;
                        visibility: hidden;
                        transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
                    }
                    &:hover:before{
                        opacity: 1;
                        visibility: visible;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not working" ?

Comment: Means media query is not working

Comment: Place you media query first  and then write your scss code inside that query
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
//your css
}

Comment: I put your code in [a codepen](https://codepen.io/MrLister/pen/ropjjM) and it works perfectly, so there is nothing wrong with the code you're showing here. Therefore, the problem must be with code you're not showing, or, your understanding of what `max-width` does.

Comment: ok Thank you very much

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use this snippet, As your Scss is not very well optimized and structured i have done this for you. Implement changes by yourself for more using media queries on css and scss plese refer to [This link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

```
.navb-header{
    .navbar-brand{
        img{width:125px;}
    }
    #navbarTogglerDemo02{
        ul{
            li.nav-item{
                padding: 0 10px;
                a{
                    font-weight: 500;
                    color: #000;
                    font-size: 16px;
                    text-transform: uppercase;
                    transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
                    position: relative;
                    &:before{
                        content:'';
                        position: absolute;
                        width: 100%;
                        height: 2px;
                        border:1px solid #333;
                        bottom:0;
                        left: 0;
                        opacity: 0;
                        visibility: hidden;
                        transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
                    }
                    &:hover:before{
                        opacity: 1;
                        visibility: visible;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
        .navbar-brand{
            img{width:345px;}
        }   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Use this link in head section so you can use a media query

Comment: That opened my eye on something, I added an admin interface without including the header or the footer.